# Convert Markdown-Docu to docx under windows without pandoc?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, markdown, gitea

I know and love pandoc, but my client wants me to regulary convert Markdown documentation (saved inside a git respository) to MS Word documents *without* using pandoc. Two alternatives I came up with so far are:

1. Use the HTML previews generated by [giteea](https://gitea.io/en-us/), save each of them as HTML or PDF and re-import those files into MS Word.
2. Use the markdown functionality of Visual Studio Code, print each page as PDF, and reimport it to MS Word.

Both approaches have the same drawbacks: They are not easy to script, require a PDF-to-Word plugin, and need manual cleansing afterwards.

My question: **Is there some magic powershell functionality or advanced command-line option of Visual Studio Code I could use?**

PS: I am aware that my request sounds rather exotic, but what can I do: The business asks for docx-files, but on the other hand, the IT side insists in Markdown (for good reasons).

### References

- [ConvertFrom-Markdown](http://%20+%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-markdown?view=powershell-7.1) sounds promising, but again only brings me to HTML.

Comment: Why do your clients care what tool you use to do this?

Comment: @Chris Well, because they have a "toolbox" of allowed software (e.g. powershell), everything else is considered *end user computing* (EUC, German: Interne Datenverarbeitung, IDV) and as such requires lenghty documentation and justification towards some control instances.

Comment: That sounds more like an employer than a client to me, but I guess that's not important. Can you use a Pandoc binary that doesn't require installation? Barring that, why not make your case and ask them to approve the software? This sounds like a pretty good argument to bring forward: "The business asks for docx-files, but on the other hand, the IT side insists in Markdown (for good reasons)". It sounds like you already have the right tool.